# Flutter: Unable to compile iOS flutter_blue

Tags: ios, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

While building on Xcode I get the following error:

`open /development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_blue-0.8.0/ios/gen/Flutterblue.pbobjc.h: No such file or directory`

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue for a different class and in my case, the problem was that my Pod repo was not up to date :|

simply ran `pod repo update` and then ran `flutter build ios` and it was fixed.